# Error reading end tag - Model parsing the xml failed

Tags: xml, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a sample exercise of creating an arm robot with 3 links and 2 joints, by defining the urdf file. Am also following the tutorial from **Mastering ROS for Robotics Programmin** by **Lentin Joseph**. I have the following code

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <robot name="pan_tilt">

    <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <material name="yellow">
            <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="pan_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="pan_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="pan_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylindder length="0.4" radius="0,04"/>
        </geomtry>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
        <material name="red">
            <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>
    
<joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">
    <parent link="pan_link"/>
    <child link="tilt_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

<link name="tilt_link">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylindder length="0.4" radius="0,04"/>
        </geomtry>
        <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0.0"/>
        <material name="green">
            <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
</link>
</robot>
```

while running

```
    check_urdf pan_tilt.urdf
```

I get the following error :

```
    Error:   Error reading end tag.
     at line 72 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
    ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
```

The code is straight out of the tutorials. Can you please point out where the mistake is?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267626/error-reading-end-tag---model-parsing-the-xml-failed/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you run into these problems, remove parts of your xml-file until you find the segment which causes your problem. (e.g.  remove first half, check if error remains and continue in binary-search-style).

With this technique, you can find the errors in your urdf quite fast (geomtry, cylindder, "0,04") which are all just simple typos.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.ros.org/users/5138/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-29**:
Thank you for your help. It worked for debug.!

**Comment by [kashifnoori](https://answers.ros.org/users/32019/kashifnoori/) on 2017-09-26**:
getting the same error ! how did you resolved it ?